# how to set proxy for telesharp

Tags: c#, proxy, bots, telegram

How can I add a proxy to my source to exclude filtering?

[my file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcXvJ.png)

```
  public class TeleShrap
{
    private WebRequest r;
    public event OnMessage NewMessageFromUser;
    public event OnMessage NewMessageFromChat;
    private bool Start { get; set; }
    private long UpdateId { get; set; }
    private string addres = "https://api.telegram.org/bot";
    public string filepth_addres = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot";
    public string token = string.Empty;
    public void StartUpdates()
    {
        Start = true;
        new Task(Updating).Start();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a description to the image link you have there, and make sure to visit our help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The TeleSharp project seems to be abandoned for years now.

I'd suggest you use the [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) library. You can find information about adding a proxy on the [Wiki](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/4/proxy.html).

Comment: I want a source for C #